# Jquery loader wont fade out

Tags: jquery

I am a bit confused about what should be a pretty basic coding test. I am using the steps from this tutorial:

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-loading-image-while-page-is.html

However, for some reason the loader.gif image appears but then never fades out. I am greatly appreciative of any help you can give.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>Test</title>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#dvLoading

{
   background:#000 url(images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="dvLoading"></div>

<img src="images/about.jpg" width="498" height="383" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could u try using `ready` event? just as a trial..

Comment: How about including jQuery ?

Comment: @adeneo good observation skill ;)

Comment: Add `Jquery` Library and add `  $(document).ready(function () {});` under the <script> tag and write your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jQuery?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: What is `rout/to/jquery.js` if you want to give answer any question please give properly. You can add src value latest `Jquery` library from google by which user can undersatnd easily.